# Mostrar dados php dentro de tabs

Tags: php

tenho uma duvida em relação as tabs. 
Anteriormente tinha os dados a serem mostrados todos dentro de uma tabela com paginação .

Agora a minha duvida é. 
com as divisões das tabs tenho de abrir e fechar o php sempre que mudo de tab?
Como consigo fazer a paginação com as tabs?

Antes tinha assim:

```
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET ['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
$sql = "select * from Tables order by tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio,   $quantidade"  ;
    $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
    echo "<table>"; 

    echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
    echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";

    echo  "<tr><td>Morada:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if ($exibe['Morada']){ echo $exibe['Morada'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

     echo  "<tr><td>Distrito:</td>"; echo "<td>";
     if ($exibe['Distrito']){ echo $exibe['Distrito'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

     echo  "<tr><td>Concelho:</td>"; echo "<td>";
     if ($exibe['Concelho']){ echo $exibe['Concelho'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";
```

Agora tenho assim sem estar preenchido:

```
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `Como consigo fazer a paginação com as tabs` não entendi? poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: No primeiro exemplo era como tinha para mostrar os dados do Mysql em forma de tabela e antes da tabela tinha a paginação. 
Mas decidi melhorar essa forma e quero que os dados do mysql aparecem em sitios diferente de forma organizada. 
Ao alterar isso fiquei sem saber onde colocar a paginação a funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Seu `PHP`deve ficar assim:

```
$i = 1;
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
echo"
<div id='tabs-".$i."'>
    <p>".$exibe['Morada']."</p>
    <p>".$exibe['Distrito']."</p>
    <p>".$exibe['Concelho']."</p>
</div>
";
$i++;
}
```

A variável `$i` esta fazendo a contagem para o `CSS` que você está aplicando, a cada `WHILE` que retorna para verificação, ele acrescenta `+1`, sendo assim quando finalizar as informações ele irá colocar cada `CSS` no devido lugar.
Caso tenha que carregar muita informações dentro da `TABS`, terá que ser feito um `ECHO` para cada `TABS`.

Comment: Uma duvida. O exemplo que deixas-te é apenas para uma tab correcto? 
E antes do $i tenho de abrir o php

Answer (score 0):

Olá. 
A melhor opção de paginação é com dados setado de `$inicio` e `$limite` fazendo apenas uma `query` dos dados desejáveis `SELECT lista FROM tablet LIMIT $inicio,$limite`. E ainda você ganha com performance de execução.

Um exemplo:

http://daltonmenezes.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/paginacao-de-resultados-com-php-e-mysql-aprenda-definitivamente-no-passo-a-passo/

---

Acho que é isto:

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET ['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
$sql = "select * from Tables order by tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio,   $quantidade"  ;
    $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

    //verificação sequencial. 
    if (!empty($exibe['Morada'])){ 
      $morada = 'N/D';
    }else{
      $morada = $exibe['Morada']
    }
    if (!empty($exibe['Distrito'])){ 
      $distrito = 'N/D';
    }else{
      $distrito = $exibe['Distrito']
    }
    if (!empty($exibe['Concelho'])){ 
      $conselho = 'N/D';
    }else{
      $conselho = $exibe['Concelho']
    }

    echo'<div id="tabs-1">
           <p>Nome: '.$exibe["Nome"].'</p>
           <p>Morada:   '.$morada.'</p>
           <p>Distrito: '.$distrito.'</p>
           <p>Concelho: '.$conselho.'</p>
         </div>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas o meu problema não é fazer a paginação pois ja a tinha feito. Mas alterei a forma de mostrar os dados e coloquei tabs e aqui sim é o meu problema.

Comment: Dentro do div tenho de abrir o php correcto?